# How to embed HTML page into outlook and gmail email body?

Tags: html, outlook

I am trying to embed my HTML page into 'outlook' and Gmail email body. I am creating a survey tool where the email contains radio buttons and submit button which sends selected data to the server.
I have tried to insert the HTML file but it gets displayed as text, please help me with input.

Is there a better way of implementing this?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

As a quick solution, you can send yourself the email using a free HTML mail editor.

You have to send it as an HTML, from your webmail provider. There is a free service for that. I use http://ctrlq.org/html-mail/

Otherwise, you have to create and send it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook will NOT run any script or submit any HTML forms from HTML emails that it displays.

Answer (score 0):

Just type the email you want in gmail. Save it as draft.

*Righ click* and *Inspect* the elements you want. Edit your email (Devevoper tools) just like you would do with a website.

Save it.

Email it.

Be happy.

Answer (score -2):

Please refer to the following solution.

http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/general-miscellaneous/how-to-send-an-html-email-from-gmail/

This is core of answer:

> 1. Use an html editor (like DreamWeaver, TextWrangler, Coda, or whatever you may have) and create the email in the editor. Then save
>      the file with a “.html” extension. Where you save the file does not
>      matter at all, but it’s probably easiest just to save the HTML file on
>      your desktop so you can easily access it in step 2.
> 2. Open that html file in an internet browser – Firefox, Safari, Internet Explorer, Google Chrome, etc. If you just click on the file
>      it should just directly open up in a browser, since your computer is
>      smart enough to know that a “.html” file should be opened in a
>      browser. If the file does not open directly in a browser, simply open
>      a browser window, and then in the browser menu go to “File->Open
>      File”, and choose the .html file.
> 3. In your browser menu, go to Edit, and then “Select All” or Ctrl+A ( or Command + A if you are on a Mac) to select everything that is
>      displayed in the browser.
>      *Copy (Ctrl + C) the now highlighted/selected page.*
>      This is the magic step that stores all the
>      HTML onto your clipboard – so make sure you get this one right!
> 4. Paste (CTRL + V or Command +V) the html to the Gmail or Yahoo Mail message. Then you are done! This should work like a charm – and you
>      should be able to see the HTML message directly in your message before
>      you send it.

Comment: doesn't work for me